# AWS Amplify and importing Lambda Layers in Python gives module not found error

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-lambda-layers

How does one import the assets of a shared lambda layer?  Following [this](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/function/layers#add-shared-assets), I have created the lambda layer, added shared code to the layer. added the layer to a function. now in the lambda function that is using the layer, how do you use the files dropped in the opt folder of the layer created? The documentation says you can look for files in the opt path of the lambda layer. But what if there are multiple lambda layers? How do you narrow the opt path down to the specific layer?

**EDIT**

My new folder structure as below. I am trying to call the common shared utility class called my_utils in the file myClass.py from Index.py and have dropped the layer function file in both `site-packages` folder as well as the `opt` folder

```
app-root
  -amplify
     -backend
        -function
          -myLayer
            -lib\python\lib\python3.8\site-packages\myClass.py
            -opt\myClass.py
  -amplify
     -backend
        -function
          -myFunction
            -Index.py
```

Below are the various combinations I tried for importing in my calling handler Index.py

```
from myClass import my_utils
import myClass
import my_utils
```

With the above arrangements and import statements, I am still getting a `ModuleNotFoundError`

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation about lambda layers.

"Layers are applied in the order that's specified, merging any folders with the same name."

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html

Importing python layers shown here: https://adhorn.medium.com/getting-started-with-aws-lambda-layers-for-python-6e10b1f9a5d

`layer 1`

```
def foo():
  print('I am from layer 1')
  return 1
```

`layer 2`

```
def bar():
  print('I am from layer 2')
  return 1
```

Then just import the function from the layers like so. It doesn't matter where they are.

`actual function`

```
import foo
import bar
```

In order for the imports to work correctly, make sure you put your layers in an `opt/python` directory and zip up the contents. I got this information from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54796202/5647552

Note:
The order of the different layers is not important unless you have layers with the same function name in them. Like if two layers were exporting the same function: `foo()`, then the order will dictate which one you import in your actual function.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. This seems to be created in the context of pure lambda and not when AWS Amplify is creating the functions. With Amplify, the layer functions get created in a different folder which is at the same level as the folder holding the calling function.

Comment: I updated question with more details for showing the folder structure in question.

Comment: The link you have above has a section about changing the order via the amplify cli, so it should be applicable

Comment: Thanks again. For sake of simplicity I am keeping just one layer function now and after checking the link you sent, I tweaked the setup a bit, but still getting the same error.

Comment: so specific to amplify, does the .py file need to be in the `lib\python\lib\python3.8\site-packages` folder or the `opt` folder and does it need to be a zip file or can it be stored there as a .py file?

Comment: I updated the answer to hopefully answer that question

Comment: thanks for your patience. None of those worked unfortunately. I keep getting a  `ModuleNotFoundError`

Comment: i struggled with the same problem and got i working with the layer-python-file in "amplify/backend/function/layerfc/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/testii.py" and the import looking as follows: import testii as tf , executing the function: tf.foo()

Comment: @user20358 I am running into a similar issue. I was able to make it work by placing the myClass.py file under myLayer\lib\python\ 

However the issue I have is that it cannot find the modules that I have in myClass.py.  Is there a folder structure that you were eventually able to work with ? It would be helpful for me.